# Div gets replaced when trying to place another div with the same class name next to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Problem:**

I have a drop down menu where colours can be selected. When a colour is selected, the dropdown menu closes and the chosen colour is represented by a box div with the background image set to an image with the chosen colour.

It's just a way to let the person using the page know what colours they selected. If they want to select more colours, they can go back to the colour menu and select another colour. When this happens, that new selected colour should be placed next to the previously selected colour.

**What I've tried:**

I'm using background images to represent the colours. Anyway, I'm not able to get my desired effect. The first select colour div just gets replaced by the new one. I've gone through a lot of posts and have tried .prepend(), .append(), .after(), .insertAfter().

I've replicated my code on JSFiddle. I have a default image that shows when the page loads, then I'm trying to append a new one each time the container that holds the div boxes is clicked.

**My code:**

HTML:

```
<div class="colour-boxes-container">
    <div class="colour-box" style="background-image: url('https://cdn.clipart.email/0197fe6d344ce508961ca63564ce8466_blue-square-clip-art-at-clkercom-vector-clip-art-online-_578-600.svg')"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".colour-boxes-container").on('click', function() {


 alert("Clicked container");

  var newSelectedColour = $(".colour-box")
       .css("background-image", "url('https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/bright-brown-leather-texture-seamless-square-background-tile-r-picture-id958497414')")

  $(".colour-box:last").after(newSelectedColour);

});
```

CSS:

```
.colour-boxes-container {
  height: 55px;
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: left;
}

.colour-box {
  height: 33px;
  width: 33px;
  margin-right: 7px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m0c8q742/1/

What could I be missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is the problem:

```
$(".colour-box")
       .css("background-image", "url('https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/bright-brown-leather-texture-seamless-square-background-tile-r-picture-id958497414')")
```

This code essentially says "Find any elements on the page with the class "colour-box" and change the CSS background image for those elements." Instead of creating a new element, you have been updating the old one.

If you want to create a new element, you can do something like:

```
$(".colour-boxes-container").on('click', function() {
  var $div = $(document.createElement('div'));
  $div.addClass('colour-box');
  $div.css("background-image", "url('https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/bright-brown-leather-texture-seamless-square-background-tile-r-picture-id958497414')")
  $(".colour-boxes-container").append($div);
});
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks. I can't believe I overlooked that.